# Save params from the first call of a recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that searches files in folders and recursivly calles itself if a subfolder occurs.
I want to optimize the search algo in that way that i can store the returned data and it's corresponding parameters.
So if a new search is issued. I can check if an equal search was made before and return the saved result instead of doing a new search.

My approach was to push the params into the resulting array at first or last. But this has to happen only one time in the whole recursion process.

This is my function:

```
/**
 * List all files that the matcher has hit
 * @param {String} start path from where to start the search
 * @param {Object} [options] search options
 * @param {RegExp} [options.matcher] expression to match while searching
 * @param {Boolean} [options.folders] search in subfolders, default = true
 * @returns {Array} files that the matcher has hit
 */
list(start, { matcher, folders = true } = {}) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(start)) throw new Error(`${start} doesn't exists.`)        
    const dir = fs.readdirSync(start)
    const files = []
    for (let iCnt = 0; iCnt < dir.length; iCnt++) {
        const item = path.resolve(start, dir[iCnt])
        let stat = fs.statSync(item)
        switch (true) {
            case stat.isDirectory() && folders:
                files.push(...list(item, { matcher, folders }))
                break
            case matcher && matcher.test(item):
                files.push(item)
                break
            case !matcher:
                files.push(item)
                break
        }
    }
    return files
}
```

I thought a lot about it. But can't get my head around.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Filesystem is volatile, you cannot reliably memoize it. What is a file was deleted or added between the calls?

Comment: As a performance hint, you can invoke `readdirSync` with `{withFileTypes: true}` and spare the `stat` call.

Comment: In that case I plan to compare the size of the start folder. My idea is to calculate the size of the data on the first search. Save all the informations I got. And when I come along a second time I only calculate the size and compare that to the saved size. If it has changed I do a new search and getting the new data, too.

Comment: @georg: But how do I do the check for the folder if I use {withFileTypes: true}? stat.isDirectory()? Or do I missing something?
Oh, ok I see. It's another object than. Got it.

Comment: @kiroshiro - What if I rename a file? No sizes change, but the search results should be different. I can see keeping information for a limited time (after all, the information is stale the moment you return it anyway, whether you intentionally keep it for a while or not), but I wouldn't try to guess whether things have changed. Also note that there are some "file system watcher" APIs you might be able to use to get a proactive notification that something has changed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Oh great idea. Thank you. But in the end the function don't has to be over the top. <- I don't know how to say it any better in english. Watching the filesystem maybe a little to much for my purpose. I just try to make my life easier. And do already know a little in advance if something has changed. I only try to find the cases where I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

When the first call in a recursive sequence is special, I usually handle it by making the recursive part a worker function, and making the main function a wrapper for it that does the special part.

In your case, that would mean renaming your existing `list` (perhaps to `listWorker`) and making a wrapper `list` function that does the caching. Roughly:

```
function list(start, { matcher, folders = true } = {}) {
    let result = getFromCache(/*...*/);
    if (!result) {
        result = listWorker(start, {matcher, folders});
        putInCache(/*...*/, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was just blocked in my mind. This makes sense. One more question. Would you save the params in the result array or would you saved in an extra place?

Comment: @kiroshiro - I'm afraid I don't understand the question...?

Comment: It's ok. Not really a problem anymore. And you already helped me a lot. :)